# Show notification badges on small taskbar buttons?

Tags: taskbar, notification-area, windows-10-v1607

Just updated Windows 10 to anniversary update and was very excited about new notification badges, only to find out that they only shown on large taskbar buttons...bummer!

Anyone know any work around this limitation? At least for the tray notifications icon. That icon doesn't change size (and area it occupies) when switching from large to small taskbar buttons, so why would it be affected by the size of taskbar buttons...

Comment: It's not supported by Microsoft. You can upvote this request to get Microsoft's attention. https://aka.ms/AA8rke1

Comment: Unfortunately they don't want my upvote..my account don't have permission